# Dismiss a dialog with Polymer core-overlay

Tags: javascript, polymer

I use Polymer [core-overlay](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-overlay) to build a dialog component (like [paper-dialog](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dialog)).

This is an example for paper-dialog:

```
<paper-dialog heading="Title for dialog">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ....</p>
  <p>Id qui scripta ...</p>
  <paper-button label="More Info..." dismissive></paper-button>
  <paper-button label="Decline" affirmative></paper-button>
  <paper-button label="Accept" affirmative autofocus></paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
```

I would like to move, in this example, the paper-button's to the paper-dialog's template.
It would otherwise lead to repetitive code if you have many dialog's with the same buttons.

After I move the buttons to the template, I can't toggle the overlay anymore.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xozikoga/1/) can you see my problem in a simplified example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<button core-overlay-toggle>OK</button>`
to `<button on-tap="{{toggle}}">OK</button>`

That will cause the button in your dialog to call the toggle function.

**Edit**

The button that has the core-overlay-toggle needs to be a child element of the core-overlay.  The following works, but the styling you had no longer applied correctly.  You'll have to add that back in to get it to do what you want.

```
<polymer-element name="x-dialog">
<template>
<style>

</style>
<button on-tap="{{toggle}}">Toggle Dialog</button>

<core-overlay id="overlay" layered backdrop>
  <content></content>
  <button core-overlay-toggle>OK</button>
</core-overlay>

</template>
<script>

Polymer('x-dialog', {

  toggle: function() {

    this.$.overlay.toggle();
  }
});

</script>
</polymer-element>

<x-dialog id="dialog" >
<h2>Dialog</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fringilla sapien sed   enim sollicitudin laoreet. Suspendisse suscipit, metus ac volutpat sodales, libero magna semper lacus, molestie fringilla massa orci ut arcu. Nullam sodales urna sit amet odio vehicula mattis.</div><br><br>


 </x-dialog>
```

Comment: That is a work-around to the problem. I want to know why the core-overlay-toggle attribute doesn't do the trick.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the structure you've set up.  If I create a core-overlay and put a button that has core-overlay-toggle in it, it works just fine.  I'm still fiddling with it.

Comment: You put the button with core-over-toggle attribute inside the <core-overlay>-tags. I think that solves the problem.